# how take a value(with _Post) inside from a while(mysqli_fetch_array)

Tags: php, cart

i try create a shopping cart.

My problem:

in a prodctslist.php i display all products(with sql query, i used mysqli_fetch_array for display), and i have put a html button "add to cart" in the loop to occur with each product. Also i have put a html input(hidden) for put there at each loop the product_id.

I want take with _POST in a ilias.php product where the client has chosen. But it post me all the product_id.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>LabTsoum</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">LabTsoum</div>
        <div class="menu">Welcome, <a class = "register" href="home.php"><?php print("$user"); ?></a> || <a class = "register" href="home.php">home</a> | <a class = "register" href="home.php">my cart</a> | <a class = "register" href="sign_out.php">sign out</a></div>

        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)
            or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
            $i=0;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $product_id[$i] = $row['product_id'];
                ?><div class= "form"><?php
                echo $product_name = $row['product_name'];
                ?></br>price: <?php
                echo $product_price = $row['product_price'];
                ?> €</br>
                <form  action="ilias.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="add2cart[]" value="<?php echo $product_id[$i]; ?>" />
                </br><input class="buttons" type="submit" value="add to cart" id="button"></div><?php
                $i=$i + 1;
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        ?>

    </div>
</body>
```

and ilias.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>LabTsoum</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">LabTsoum</div>
        <div class="menu">Welcome, <a class = "register" href="home.php"><?php print("$user"); ?></a> || <a class = "register" href="home.php">home</a> | <a class = "register" href="home.php">my cart</a> | <a class = "register" href="sign_out.php">sign out</a></div>

        <?php

            foreach($_POST['add2cart'] as $i=>$s){
                echo $_POST['add2cart'][$i];
                }


        ?>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is wrong with this? Product ID is all you need... P.s. you are not supposed to do this: ` id="button"`. You should only have 1 ID per page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good that you only see the ID there.

In you ilias.php, use below code. This will give you all the data for the product.

```
foreach($_POST['add2cart'] as $i=>$s){
    if(is_numeric(mysql_real_escape_string($s)){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = " . $s . "";
        $rs = mysql_query($sql);
        $r = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
        var_dump($r); 
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to have an array, change

```
<input type="hidden" name="add2cart[]" ... />
```

to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="add2cart" ... />
```

And get the product like so:

```
$product_id = $_POST['add2cart'];
if(is_numeric(mysql_real_escape_string($product_id)){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = " . $product_id . "";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    var_dump($r); 
}
```

And don't forget to use the `</form>` tag

You won't however be able to create a real shopping cart without storing the product ID's in session

Comment: if don't used array a take to ilias.php last value from while loop. I want to take product_id from client choice

Comment: If you don't want an array, change this: `<input type="hidden" name="add2cart[]" ... />` to: `<input type="hidden" name="add2cart" ... />`

Comment: thnx i fix that.  problem was here </form>

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

There is no ending `</form>` tag. If you want to use the submit button you will need to have a new form for each iteration.

```
// ...within loop
<form  action="ilias.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="add2cart[]" value="<?php echo $product_id[$i]; ?>" />
  </br><input class="buttons" type="submit" value="add to cart" id="button"></div>
</form>
```

Secondly, although valid code, you might no want to submit the id as an array:

`<input type="hidden" name="add2cart[]" value="<?php echo $product_id[$i]; ?>" />`

You could consider removing the `[]`

Comment: I don't believe it. I will couldn't see that silly mistake never. Thanks. Firstly, of course i don't used array, sipmly i was trying find the problem.